# Is it bad practice to execute this query in a for or foreach-loop?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**So I have the following query:**

```
$resclients=$mysqli->query("SELECT id,client_name FROM clients WHERE id IN ($result[])");
```

And I am wondering, is it bad practice to execute the above query in a for or foreach-loop, does it hurt the MySQL server?

Or, is it better to do **LEFT JOINS** or **INNER JOINS** or **RIGHT JOINS**?

Forgot to add, the $result[] is actually a  two dimensional array.

Show your array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [resclients] => 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [resclients] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [resclients] => 4
        )
)
```

Just a small portion of it.

Comment: *Is it bad practice* - This can be opinionated depending on how or where you have been taught.

Comment: its depend on $result

Comment: convert your array into comma seperated using implode() than use ids in query, in this case no need to use query in loop

Comment: For example, I have a KEY in my result, to access it I need to $result[0][key], that key index provides "x, x, x, x," group_concat result.

Comment: plz show your array...

Comment: @devpro, see my edit, I added a small portion of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as:

```
// a testing multidimensional array
$testArr = array(
        array(
            'one'=>1,
            'two'=>2,
            'three'=>3)
        );

$yourIds = array();
foreach ($testArr as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $finalVal) {
        $yourIds[] = $finalVal[];
    }   
}

$implodedIds = implode(",",$yourIds);
echo "SELECT id,client_name FROM clients WHERE id IN ($implodedIds)";
```

**Result:**

```
SELECT id,client_name FROM clients WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

**Note that:** this is basic idea how can you use without using query in a loop.

Comment: Did you TL;DR my question? Can you explain this code, as I am unable to follow it entirely, very unclear, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I need to run the query and access data from the did like this, $result[0][resclients], see my array, each INDEX provides a resclients key which hold concatenated results using GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: These are ids = 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15.

Comment: 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15   for ist, and 5,4 for others... if u want to get result together, than no need to use loop @JohnSmith

Comment: if process different for all three arrays than u need to use in loop, @JohnSmith

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100755/discussion-between-devpro-and-john-smith).